# Power Steering leaks oil on my 98 Honda accord 2.3L

Tags: power-steering-fluid

power steering oil leaks and makes noise when I turn the steering wheel. Can anyone suggest what it could be?

Answer (score 1):

It could be the power steering reservoir or the steering rack or anything between the 2. A mechanic would visually inspect for the source of the leak. If he can't initially find it, he would clean around all lines and components and use dye to locate the source. He would then bleed the system and make sure the pump is good. Find a reputable shop and have it inspected. You don't want to have a sudden steering loss.